# Hypothesis testing with finite interval as null hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni

There exist two-tailed tests ($H_0: \mu = c$) and one-tailed tests ($H_0: \mu \leq c$ and $H_0: \mu \geq c$).

I am interested in the case of the null hypothesis being an interval, that is $H^{ab}_0: \mu \in [a,b]$ for finite $a,b$, with respect to significance level $\alpha$.

**How to achieve this?**

A straightforward approach suggests to combine the one-sided test $H^a_0: \mu \geq a$ with $H^b_0: \mu \leq b$. That is, $H^{ab}_0$ holds true if and only if both of $H^a_0$ and $H^b_0$ hold true. Bonferroni correction suggests to run the tests $H^a_0$ and $H^b_0$ with significance level $\alpha/2$ each, in order to get the overall significance level $\alpha$ for $H_0^{ab}$. Care must be taken on the fact that the hypotheses $H^a_0$ and $H^b_0$ are *not* independent, since they are carried out on the same data sample that is given to test $H^{ab}_0$. But since Bonferroni correction can even be applied to dependent hypotheses, this is a valid approach. Same holds for Holm-Bonferroni, which slightly improves over Bonferroni here: after computing both p-values, rejection is performed at level $\alpha/2$ for the smaller p-value and at level $\alpha$ for the larger p-value. An alternative way that allows to apply correction methods that require independency is to separate the given data in two halves (if possible) and then apply $H^a_0$ and $H^b_0$ on a separate part of the data each, but this reduces the size of each test statistic to $n/2$.

All this is very new to me, so I wonder whether these straightforward approaches are the way how one solves this problem? Or are there other, better, more direct approaches to an interval hypothesis test?

Comment: The Bonferroni correction does not require tests to be independent. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction

Comment: Thank you! I stumbled upon some misleading reference text before. So, even Holm-Bonferroni does not require independence! I edited my question, which now simply reduces to the question whether this is the best way of how to achieve this?